# Adapt ajax for crossdomain

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

Is it possible adapt this code for crossdomain and how

```
function makeRequest(url) {

    var http_request = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
                http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }

    if (!http_request) {
        alert('Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }

    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(http_request); };
    http_request.open('GET', url, true);
    http_request.send(null);
}

function alertContents(http_request) {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
        if (http_request.status == 200) {
            receiveData(http_request.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("Îòâåò ñåðâåðà ïîëó÷åí, íî åñòü îøèáêà");
        }         
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents JavaScript reading data from different origins under normal circumstances.

You can work around with:

1. A proxy for the data on the page's origin
2. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
3. [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) ([limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors), but possibly good enough for prime time now)