# How to get the html code from a web page (different domain)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing

How can I create a javascript script that allows me to get the html code of a different page from a different domain and allows me to edit and display the code?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by ' allows me to edit and display the code' ?

Comment: I want to be able to parse the html and change it a little

Comment: It can be done with a CGI/Perl script on your server and then retrieved by your page to be manipulated with JavaScript.  Not posting as an answer since you're not asking about CGI or Perl although it will ultimately get you to the same place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adapt ajax for crossdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640633/adapt-ajax-for-crossdomain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in the naive sense because you will get killed by javascript's same domain policy.

Now if you have access to your own web server, you could set up a service that listens for your request which would include a 3rd party URL to fetch. Your service would pull the source for the 3rd party domain and return it as the response to your request. Then you take that response and append it into your editable field.

EDIT: This answer seems to be the same principle as the YQL (Yahoo Query Language) answer that was posted as well.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Cross-domain requests with jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/)).

Comment: The link in this answer is broken.

Comment: Well, this answer is almost 11 years old.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Cross domain scripting is not possible... you can also search SO and find many answers to this question.

Comment: [There are workarounds.](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide)