# How to fetch a specific div id from an html file through ajax

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have two html files called **index.html** & **video.html**

**video.html** holds coding like:

```
<div id="video">
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tJFUqjsBGU4?html5=1" width=500 height=500></iframe>
</div>
```

I want the above mentioned code to be crawled from video.html page from index.html

I can't use any back-end coding like php or .net

Is there any way to do using Ajax?

Comment: Ya, you can use ajax for sure... Let me ask you, what have you tried?

Comment: AJAX requires actually some "backend" coding ;)

Comment: Can u share the code?

Comment: You can access YouTUbe data via de Google API. Perhaps this is easier.

Comment: Are the pages on the same domain? Otherwise it's impossible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853641/how-to-get-the-html-code-from-a-web-page-different-domain

Comment: @abimelex: Yes. same domain only

Comment: @abimelex even not on same domain you could proxified it server side in most case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$.ajax({
url: 'video.html',
success: function(data) {
    mitem=$(data).filter('#video');
    $(selector).html(mitem); //then put the video element into an html selector that is on your page.
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Blachawk. I just added $("#wrapper").html(mitem) to bring the fetched html from external page.

Comment: You're Welcome.  Happy to help. And yes that is what I meant to say too!  That was an overlook on my part.  It is now updated.

Answer (score 1):

For sure,send an ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'video.html',
success: function(data) {
    data=$(data).find('div#video');
   //do something

 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this is a perfect use case for ajax. When you make the `$.ajax()` request to your video.html page, you can then treat the response similar to the way you'd treat the existing DOM.

For example, you'd start the request by specifying the URI in the the following way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'video.html'
})
```

You want to make sure that request succeeds. Luckily jQuery will handle this for you with the `.done` callback:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "video.html",
}).done(function ( data ) {});
```

Now it's just a matter of using your `data` object in a way similar to the way you'd use any other jQuery object. I'd recommend the `.find()` method.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "video.html",
}).done(function ( data ) {

    $(data).find('#video'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your step by step explanation

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned crawl, I assume there is the possibility of multiple pages.  The following loads pages from an array of urls, and stores the successful loads into results.  It decrements remainingUrls (which could be useful for updating a progressbar) on each load (`complete` is called after `success` or `error`), and can call a method after all pages have been processed `(!remainingUrls)`.

If this is overkill, just use the `$.ajax` part and replace `myUrls[i]` with `video.html`.  I sepecify the `type` only because I ran into a case where another script changed the default type of ajax to POST.  If you're loading dynamic pages like php or aspx, then the `cache` property might also be helpful if you're going to call this multiple times per session.

```
    var myUrls = ['video1.html', 'video2.html', 'fail.html'],
        results = [],
        remainingUrls;


    $(document).ready(function () {
        remainingUrls = myUrls.length;
        for (var i = 0, il = myUrls.length; i < il; i++) {
            $.ajax({
                url: myUrls[i],
                type: 'get', // somebody might override ajax defaults
                cache: 'false', // only if you're getting dynamic pages
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('success');
                    results.push(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('fail');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    remainingUrls--;
                    if (!remainingUrls) {
                        // handle completed crawl
                        console.log('done');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but should be something similair to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3535356/1059828

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'index.html', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (this.readyState!==4) return;
    if (this.status!==200) return; // or whatever error handling you want
    document.getElementsByTagName('html').innerHTML= this.responseText;
};
xhr.send();
```