# Can I get a portion of an external domain's html?

Tags: jquery, html, rss

I am using an RSS feed to display news on my site.  I am using the link to the actual story to try and get the full content of the article and post it directly on my website so people don't leave to read the story.  I thought I could do this with jQuery's load function but have since found out this doesn't work across domains.  Can any suggest anything else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adapt ajax for crossdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640633/adapt-ajax-for-crossdomain)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the html code from a web page (different domain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853641/how-to-get-the-html-code-from-a-web-page-different-domain)

Comment: *"...and get the full content of the article and post it directly on my website so people don't leave..."* In other words, you want to rip off someone else's content with as little effort as possible. You better examine the usage policies of those news sites. I doubt they let you republish their content for free.

Comment: well no not rip off, it's a site for the local community, so I wanted to tie everything together, I'm not trying to maliciously steal content for my own gain thank you very much

Comment: So you're the publisher of the news content, or you have special permission from the publisher to redistribute their content?

Comment: try and paint me how you want, it's a simple question that required an answer not a judgment

Comment: Well you're the one trying to prevent visitors to another site by taking their work and putting it on your site. I'm just letting you know that depending on the source of the content, it's likely not allowed. Intellectual property is a very real thing, and there are laws that enforce it. You should be thanking me.

Comment: @Nicola — If the content owners are on board then they should have no problem providing you with a full text RSS feed thus avoiding the need for all this cross-domain mucking about.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks, I'll ask them about this.  I've never used an RSS feed before.  Won't it mean a lot of work for them adding extra content?

Comment: @Nicola — It shouldn't be. The content is already there, the feed is already there, they just need to tweak the feed to include it (or duplicate the feed script and tweak that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load content from external domains - read up here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

If I was you I'd make a small page using server side language like PHP that can retrieve what you need from an external domain and use jQuery's AJAX to call your PHP script.

Comment: it's possible but against same origin policy ;-)

Comment: same origin policy doesn't apply to server side languages.

Comment: I think that is what I am doing.  I'm following advice from [link]http://www.sitegrind.nl/jquery/jquery-load-function-get-content-from-other-websites/comment-page-1/#comment-121[link].  However, it's not loading due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin says Chrome

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I wasn't aware there was an issue about this, never mind a policy!  Cheers for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `.load()` to load content from other website that's against the same origin policy. 
But there is a jQuery plugin which allows you to do that:

- http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/

Answer (score 0):

As I know, it's impossible to get content from another domain for security reasons.
You can proxy such requests by your server.

Comment: that's right its against security reasons but it's possible ;-)

Comment: But nevertheless it's impossible to load some page from another domain. It's possible to load data in JSON format from another domain and then convert it to origin format client-side. Some jQuery plugins works using own "json proxy". It's also possible to load origin page using proxy on the same domain.